# Data Binding from TableSelectDialog to Form

Tags: sapui5

I'm using TableSelectDialog to view some *Carrier* details. All I need is: If I select any item (row), then all the values from that row should get automatically populated to the form input fields.

[image]

In the attached image, if *Carrier Name* is selected from TableSelectDialog, then the remaining fields should be populated based on that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the required functionality using the Binding context that you receive from the TableSelcect Dialog.

But for binding context to work properly, both form and the table select dialog should refer to the same Model.

Below is the working code:

**VIEW.XML:**

1. Has a Button to trigger the table select dialog.
2. Has a form.

> ```
> <l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
>   <l:content>
>       <Button class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom" text="Show Table Select Dialog"
>           press="handleTableSelectDialogPress">
>       </Button>
>       <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
>           <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormDisplay354">
>               <f:content>
>                   <Label text="Supplier Name" />
>                   <Text id="nameText" text="{SupplierName}" />
>                   <Label text="Description" />
>                   <Text text="{Description}" />
>                   <Label text="ProductId" />
>                   <Text text="{ProductId}" />
>                   <Label text="Quantity" />
>                   <Text id="countryText" text="{Quantity}" />
>               </f:content>
>           </f:SimpleForm>
>       </VBox>
>   </l:content>
> </l:VerticalLayout>
> ```

**Controller:**

```
        onInit: function () {
    // set explored app's demo model on this sample
    var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.mock", "/products.json"));
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
},
handleTableSelectDialogPress: function (oEvent) {
    if (!this._oDialog) {
        this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.m.sample.TableSelectDialog.Dialog", this);
    }

    this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog);

    // toggle compact style
    this._oDialog.open();
},
handleClose: function (oEvent) {
    var aContexts = oEvent.getParameter("selectedContexts");
    if (aContexts && aContexts.length) {
        //              MessageToast.show("You have chosen " + aContexts.map(function(oContext) { return oContext.getObject().Name; }).join(", "));
        this.byId('SimpleFormDisplay354').setBindingContext(aContexts[0]);
    }
    oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items").filter([]);
}
```

Now, we also have a Select dialog and on click of any Item we call method : `handleClose`

In `handleClose`, we obtain the clicked Item binding context and then tell the form : hey! refer to this context ( which is present in the model). Binding context has a path which tells the form from where to do the relative binding.

Please feel free to contact for more information.